# if statement for string comparison is not executing properly

Tags: c, string, input, printf, scanf

I am trying to write a simple program for finding out areas of different shapes.The program is compiled fine but when it runs it does not give me the right answer.  I mean When it runs it asks:

> What do you want to find area of?

and when I type

> square

or anything else and hit enter it just ends,it doesn't execute any other code.

The code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    char yourchoice[40]="";
    float a=0;; //a=height
    float b=0; //b=breadth
    float Sq,Rec,Parall,trap,cir,ell,tri;

    printf("Here You can find out areas of Square,Rectangle,Parallelogram,trapezoid,circle,ellipse and triangle \n\n\n");

    printf("what do u want to find area of? : \n");
    scanf(" %s",yourchoice);

    if(yourchoice[40]== 'square'){
        printf("Length of any side of the square =");
        scanf(" %f",&a);
        Sq = pow(a,2);
        printf("Area of the Square is %f",&Sq);
    }else if(yourchoice== 'rectangle')
    {
        printf("Height = \n");
        scanf("%f",a);
        printf("Width=\n");
        scanf("%f",b);
        Rec= a*b;
        printf("Area of the Rectangle : %f ",&Rec);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What I never understand is why classes for beginners in C use string I/O first. Is there nothing to start out with which is more suitable? It is a system programming language, not some general purpose high level app language, after all. So why bother with strings in the start?

Comment: Also: Remove the `&` in the `printf` statements

Comment: regarding this line: 'char yourchoice[40]="";' this results in yourchoice containing: '\0'. + 30 bytes of garbage.  a much better initialization would be: char yourchoice[40] = {'\0'};  which fills yourchoice with '\0' (NUL) characters.

Comment: regarding the method of inputting the users' choice, a much better method would be to (in a loop) display a menu, where each possible selection is a single digit rather than a string.   BTW: this line: 'scanf(" %s",yourchoice);' has a couple of problems: 1) the returned value from the call to scanf (not the parameter) needs to be checked to assure the operation was successful.  2) a "%s" format specifier has not length limit, so the user can easily overrun the input buffer.  suggest: 'scanf(" %39s",yourchoice);' which limits the input to 39 characters + the NUL char supplied by scanf

Comment: regarding this kind of line: if(yourchoice[40]== 'square'){'' 1) offset/index 40 is beyond the bounds of the yourchoice array, which results in undefined behaviour an leads to a seg fault event  2) strings are compared to string, not an int ('square' is an integer) 3) the proper way to compare a string is: if( !strcmp( yourchoice, "square" ) ) { // then strings are equal }  Notice the use of double quotes '"' when creating a string literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Point 1:**

Use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) for string comparison, not `==` operator.

**Point 2:**

Anyways, for an array of `char yourchoice[40]="";`, using `yourchoice[40]` is out of bounds which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Array index in `C` starts from 0.

**Point 3:**

`printf()` does not need to have a pointer to data argument. Change

```
printf("Area of the Square is %f",&Sq);
printf("Area of the Rectangle : %f ",&Rec);
```

to

```
printf("Area of the Square is %f\n", Sq); //& not required
printf("Area of the Rectangle : %f\n",Rec); //& not required
```

**Point 4:**

`scanf()` requires a pointer to data type argument .Change

```
scanf("%f",a);
scanf("%f",b);
```

to

```
scanf("%f", &a); // & is required
scanf("%f", &b); // & is required
```

**Point 5:** <sup>With thanks to Mr. **@Mints97**</sup>

You need to use `" "` to denote a *string literal*. `' '`
 is used to represent a `char`. These two are different.

**General Suggestion:**

1. The recommended prototype for `main()` is `int main(void)`
2. Always initialize all of your local variables.

Comment: thanks you very much bro,really appreciate that and btw....
do we only use == in c for comparing ints and single characters  to the left hand side??

Comment: @gurpindersingh see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_comparison) for some clarification. if you use strings as the operands of `==` operator, their base address gets comapred, not their contents. Hope that make things clear . :-)

Comment: You forgot to point out that strings in C can be only double-quoted. `'square'` is not actually a string =)

Comment: regarding this line, in the posted fix: 'scanf("%f",b); // & is required'  a bit of a slip of the fingers, as the 'required' '&' is missing.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using

```
if(yourchoice[40]== 'square')
```

`yourchoice[40]` is only a single character you are comparing with a string.
And even it is wrong as you have declared `char yourchoice[40]` means index will be from `0` to `39`.
use `strcmp` function to compare strings.
If strings are equal it will return `0`, otherwise `1` or `-1`.
Use

```
if(strcmp(yourchoice, "square") == 0)
```

Or

```
if(!strcmp(yourchoice, "square"))
```

---

And in your `printf` statement don't use `&` to print variable value.

Change these line

```
printf("Area of the Square is %f",&Sq);
printf("Area of the Rectangle : %f ",&Rec);
```

to

```
printf("Area of the Square is %f",Sq);
printf("Area of the Rectangle : %f ",Rec);
```

---

And in your else part you forget to add `&` in your `scanf`

Change these lines

```
scanf("%f",a);
scanf("%f",b);
```

To

```
scanf("%f",&a);  // in scanf, '&' is required.
scanf("%f",&b);
```

Comment: thanks bros ....
Really appreciate that...
i am just starting to learn c and it seems like bhool-bhoolaya :(

Comment: C only has ~7 statements and a bunch of system calls.  so learn the 7 statements, then always look up the syntax for the system calls, until you are fully familiar with those calls. (I've been programming C for ~20 years and still look up system calls that I rarely use.)

Answer (score 1):

There are many mistakes in your code. strings are compared using `strcmp` and not `==`

your

`if(yourchoice[40]== 'square')`

should be

```
if(0 == strcmp(yourchoice, "square"))
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your statement, it's 100% OK, but just from a preference standpoint, I usually read it `if(strcmp(yourchoice, "square") == 0)`. That's generally because you think **"If what...was it again?"** , oh, `if(strcmp...`, rather than `if(0...`? Completely up to you.

Comment: I prefer the habit of always placing the literal on the left, then when the comparison should be '==' but only '=' was entered, then the compiler catches the error rather than my having to debug the code to find the problem.  I.E. when I can let the compiler do the work, I let it.   Speaking of compiler, always compile with all warnings enabled, then fix the warnings. (and the posted code has a bunch of warnings that need fixing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare C strings with `==`. You need `strcmp()`. And `''` is used for a single character, not for a string.

So, change

```
if(yourchoice[40]== 'square')
```

to

```
if( !strcmp(yourchoice, "square"))
```

and

```
else if(yourchoice== 'rectangle')
```

to

```
else if(!strcmp(yourchoice, "rectangle"))
```

BTW, you need to include `<string.h>` for `strcmp()`

Also, change

```
printf("Area of the Square is %f",&Sq);
```

to

```
printf("Area of the Square is %f", Sq);
                                   ^ 
                                   no need of &
```

and

```
printf("Area of the Rectangle : %f ",&Rec);
```

to

```
printf("Area of the Rectangle : %f ",Rec);
```

When you put `&` before an identifier, it returns the address of that identifier. You don't need to use `&` in `printf()`

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    char yourchoice[40]="";
    float a=0;; //a=height
    float b=0; //b=breadth
    float Sq,Rec,Parall,trap,cir,ell,tri;

    printf("Here You can find out areas of Square,Rectangle,Parallelogram,trapezoid,circle,ellipse and triangle \n\n\n");

    printf("what do u want to find area of? : \n");
    scanf(" %s",yourchoice);

//Here, strcmp is the prefered way to compare the strings
//string.h is the header to use it
// It returns 0 when the string match
    //if(yourchoice == 'square'){
    if(!strcmp(yourchoice,"square")){
        printf("Length of any side of the square =");
        scanf(" %f",&a);
        Sq = pow(a,2);
//Second correction: & are to used only when storing the input and not while accessing or displaying it.So, in scanf you have to use but not for printf statements

    printf("Area of the Square is %f",Sq);
    }
    else if(!strcmp(yourchoice,"rectangle"))
    {
        printf("Height = \n");
//Third Correction, in the org code you had missed to write "&" before the variable 'a'
        scanf("%f",&a);
        printf("Width=\n");
//Fourth Correction, in the org code you had missed to write "&" before the variable 'b'
        scanf("%f",&b);
        Rec= a*b;
//Fifth correction: Same as second correction. Not to use '&' sign in printf statements

        printf("Area of the Rectangle : %f ",Rec);

    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is this? Where is there any explanation about why you posted this block of code. I would suggest you explain it's purpose, otherwise others may not find it to be an informative answer. Compare with the other answers.